# Particle moving on curve which is the intersection of a surface and a plane

Tags: plotting, homework

Surface

```
z = 2 x^3 - 5 y^4
```

Plane

```
z = x + y + 5
```

Plot

[image]

A curve is formed by the intersection of the surface and the plane.
I would like to add a point to the plot that can be moved by the user along the curve of intersection.

---

Thanks!!!

to work animation, i had to change line

```
anim = Table[
   Show[p3D, Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point[par[j]]}], 
    ViewPoint -> {-1, -1, 1}], {j, -10, 10, 0.1}];
```

to:

`Animate[Show[p3D,Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02],Point[par[j]]}],ViewPoint->{-1,-1,1}],{j,-10,10,0.1}]`

But where is
equation of motion of the material point in this solution?

Comment: And have you looked up the documentation page for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html#1766845292)?

Comment: Fully agree with @march. Try to use Solve to figure out the function of crossing, then use Manipulate to show it.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `MeshFunctions` to visualize the intersection. The following  is one way to parametrize curve.

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 x^3 - 5 y^4;
p[x_, y_] := x + y + 5;
expr = x /. Quiet[First@Solve[f[x, y] == p[x, y], {x, y}, Reals]];
t[u_] := expr /. y -> u;
par[w_] := {t[w], w, p[t[w], w]};
p3D = Plot3D[{f[x, y], p[x, y]}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (f[#1, #2] - p[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
anim = Table[
   Show[p3D, Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point[par[j]]}], 
    ViewPoint -> {-1, -1, 1}], {j, -10, 10, 0.1}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A modification of @ubpdqn's approach using `MeshFunctions` to show the boundary of the two surfaces:

We can use a *function* as the setting for `MeshStyle`. Doing so we can inject additional primitives (e.g., `Sphere`s) using the coordinates of mesh lines. Using `Clock` + `Dynamic`,  we can make these additional primitives dynamic.

```
meshStyle = {Red, Thick, #, Opacity[1], Specularity[Yellow, 50], Green, 
   Dynamic @ Sphere[#[[1, Clock[{1, Length[#[[1]]], 1}, 5]]], 1]} &;

f[x_, y_] := 2 x^3 - 5 y^4;
p[x_, y_] := x + y + 5;

Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (f[#1, #2] - p[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> meshStyle, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot3D[p[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None,  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2, Blue]], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

**Note:** The price we pay is to plot the two surfaces separately. If we use a single `Plot3D` with two functions in the first argument, then we get two mesh lines (one for each surface) that do not necessarily have identical coordinates and using `MeshStyle -> meshStyle` gives double spheres.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct the parametric curve `g[y]` by using `y` as variable and only use `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
f[x_, y_] = 2 x^3 - 5 y^4;
p[x_, y_] = x + y + 5;
g[y_] = Block[{x}, {x, y, p[x, y]} /. 
    Solve[f[x, y] == p[x, y], x, Reals]];
fig1 = Plot3D[{p[x, y], f[x, y]}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], Mesh -> None];
fig2 = ParametricPlot3D[g[y], {y, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Manipulate[
 Show[fig1, fig2, Graphics3D[{PointSize[.03], Point[g[y]]}], 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], {{y, -5}, -10, 10}]
```

[image]